# EXECUTE in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

```
create table x(y number, z character varying(100))

insert into x values (1,'foo');
insert into x values (2,'bar');

do $$
declare
k character varying(100);
begin    
   EXECUTE 'SELECT z FROM '
||quote_ident(x)
 into k;
RAISE NOTICE '%',k;
end;
$$ language 'plpgsql';

ERROR:  column "x" does not exist
        LINE 2:     ||quote_ident(x)
                      ^
        QUERY:  SELECT 'SELECT z FROM '
               ||quote_ident(x)
               CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 7 at 
               EXECUTE
               SQL state: 42703
```

May I know what am I doing wrong here and I'm on 9.5. Even `EXECUTE` format is also giving me the same error.

Comment: Try `quote_ident('x')`

Comment: thanks, but what to do in case of a input parameter?

Comment: If normally `x` is function argument holding table name as text representation, then it will work like in your example and there is no need to modify it.

Comment: thanks, it worked like that.

Comment: user1720827 please answer yourself (on behalf of Lukasz) or @ŁukaszKamiński, please post it, or delete the question?..

Answer (score 0):

```
   do $$
   declare
   k character varying(100);
   begin    
  EXECUTE 'SELECT z FROM '
  ||quote_ident('x')
   into k;
  RAISE NOTICE '%',k;
  end;
  $$ language 'plpgsql';
```

quotes around 'x' worked for me. Thanks